# I want to know the count of each item in a list

Tags: c#, list, count

So, I have a list with votes.

```
List<string> Votes = new List<string>();
```

with a maximum of three diferent strings. And I want to get a count of them. this is in c#.

I've looked through earlier questions, but haven't found anything similar without the problem being way more complicated than mine.
sorry if this has already been answered

Comment: Could you give us a bit of your code to help us to understand your issue and help you ?

Comment: List<string> Stemmen = new List<string>();
I'm trying to get all distinct votes out of it. So like 5 people voted on Pepsi, 3 on Coke and 5 were indifferent

Comment: @JulesVerdonck if you meant `new List<string>();` you should actually show it in your question. Details matter.

Comment: How do you fill the list, what types do you put into?

Comment: That's not nearly enough to let us know what you want to do.  Please provide example input, current output, and desired output along with your attempted code.

Comment: like there are only three different strings possible (through the program: Pepsi, Coke and Indifferent)

Comment: I strongly suggest to read the [How To Ask page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and other topics in the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). The way your question is worded right now we can't really identify the problem. And: welcome to SO! Don't let this frighten you off! :-)

Comment: 3 unique strings that are repeated?  So you wan to know how many of each?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/EfhPLg6.png

Comment: Rather than post an image you should update your question to precisely state that.  Though you've already got a couple of valid answers using `GroupBy`.

Comment: On another note instead of a `List<string>` you might want to use a `Dictionar<string, int>` instead and initialize it with the 3 strings and a value of zero for each, then instead of adding a string to the list you'd increment the corresponding int value for that string in the dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `GroupBy`:

```
var voteGroups = Votes.GroupBy(s => s);
```

Now, if you want to know the count of each `string` use `Enumerable.Count`:

```
foreach(var voteGroup in voteGroups)
    Console.WriteLine("Vote:{0} Count:{1}", voteGroup.Key, voteGroup.Count());
```

Another way is using `ToLookup`:

```
var voteLookup = Votes.ToLookup(s => s);
foreach (var voteGroup in voteLookup)
    Console.WriteLine("Vote:{0} Count:{1}", voteGroup.Key, voteGroup.Count());
```

The lookup has it's advantages, it enables you to find specific elements like a dictionary. So you could get the "pepsi"-count in this way:

```
int pepsiCount = voteLookup["Pepsi"].Count();
```

This does not cause an exception if there is no such string in the list(count will be 0).

if you want to make it case insensitive, so treat "pepsi" and "Pepsi" as equal:

```
var voteLookup = Votes.ToLookup(s => s, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 5):

Eh, *Linq* like that?:

```
  List<String> votes = new List<String>() {
    "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "?"
  };
  ...
  String report = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, votes
    .GroupBy(item => item)
    .Select(chunk => String.Format("{0} votes, count {1}", chunk.Key, chunk.Count())) 
  );

  Console.Write(report);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the best code, but it works:

```
int count1 = 0;
int count2 = 0;
foreach (String answer in Votes)
{
  if (answer == "yes")
  {
    count1++;
  }
  if (answer == "no")
  {
    count2++;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're just trying to get the total number of unique items in your list:

```
int count = (from x in lst select x).Distinct().Count();
```

Comment: First this is not what the OP wants, see the up-voted answers.  Further why wouldn't you just do `lst.Distinct().Count()`?

Answer (score -2):

If all you have is a `List` of `strings`, then you can just use the `Count` property.

```
List<string> Votes = new List<string>();
// populate list here
Console.WriteLine(Votes.Count);
```

Comment: `Count()` is an extension of IEnumerable<T>, so it works as well.

Comment: Anyway OP wants the count of different items in the list.

Comment: @ArthurRey probably, but IMHO the OP hasn't clearly stated that yet.

Comment: @ArthurRey From what the way the question is currently written, it sounds like it's a `List` with a maximum of three values, and he wants to know how many are in the `List` at some time.

Comment: @Nik If you look at the image link the OP just posted I think it makes it more clear that Arthur is right.

Comment: @Nik: i also initially thought that but i think that the list actually is larger but can contain only three different strings which means there are a lot of duplicates. Now he wants to know the count of each of the three.

Comment: Sorry for being vague. I mean there can be three different strings multiple times in the list. I want the amount of times a specific string is in the list

Answer (score -2):

Try this...

```
var l = new List();
l.Add("abcd");
l.Add("abcd123");
l.Add("abcd1234");

var d = l.ToDictionary<string,int>(k=>k, v=>v.Length);

var count = d["abcd"]; //result would be 4.
```

Comment: This tells you how many characters each string has.  And would throw an exception if there are duplicate strings in the list, which is the case here.